# reCAPTCHA 2.0 text display

Tags: captcha, recaptcha

I'm interested in using reCAPTCHA 2.0 on my site. I've managed to implement it, but can only choose between the two options (images or audio) as described in the Google Developers manual, as seen below in the `data-type` row.

[image]

However, in the Google Developer FAQ, they show a reCAPTCHA 2.0 displaying scrambled text to the user instead. I'd like to achieve that functionality, but I can't seem to find any mention of how to implement it anywhere.

[image]

**Is it possible to implement a reCAPTCHA 2.0 with text as opposed to images? What tag attribute/JS API should be used to achieve this?**

Comment: seems to me it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

ReCaptcha changes the ways it displays captchas by the number of captchas you've solved in a certain time period.

If you solve one or two, you'll just need to check a box.

After that, you'll be asked to compare images - with there usually being between 2 and 3 correct answers.

Then you'll be asked to compare images where there are up to 4 correct answers, usually the answers make up a picture as a whole.

The final step (at least that I've seen) once you've solved a large number of captchas in a short time period, is the text verification. The whole point in ReCaptcha is to avoid giving that annoying text verification, so it makes sense that Google would use it as a last resort.

To properly answer your question, there's nothing in the google docs or (that I can find) online which permits manually choosing the type of ReCaptcha Google displays to your users - Google handles that dynamically. You're better off going with any other captcha verification which permits this.